# Size of video for android for high and medium resolution?

Tags: android, video

I have a server where I can put different videos which will be shown the Android user on request. I and to show user two options to watch videos

1 = High resolution videos
2 = Medium resolution videos

That's because user can have a low internet connection or may be high internet connection. So It depend on user which quality of video he want to chose.

I don't know what should be the size and resolution of videos HD and MD? I mean to say What is the best size for which I have to create my Videos for HD , and for MD?

Its the video size , resolution , FPS , Video bitrate , audio bit rate?

Comment: Please improve your question. It's very hard to figure out what you mean.

Comment: I dont understand why guys here downvoted it, question is simple how to record video in different reolutions?

Comment: Where did you read that he wants to *record* videos *(e.g. opposed to optimizing the performance while displaying)*? The -1 came exactly from that: The question is not clear.

Comment: "I don't know what should be the size and resolution of videos for above? " This line clearly states that he wants to record video of higher resolution above 768x480 and he doesn't know how to specify that, as per my common sense I think he wants to record not display which specially is not possible bcoz that depend on the resolution of recorded video

Comment: Sorry! I just explain the question in more detail. Hope its simple and understandable now.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> Video resolution   Lower quality = 176 x 144 px                      Higher quality = 480 x 360 px

Answer (score 1):

For creating HD and MD resolutions of a video, first you must know the pixel density of the target device that will play the video. If you don't know, you must create multiple HD and MD videos for each pixel density category.

Categories:

- HDPI(160 pixel per inch)
- MDPI(240 pixel per inch)
- XHDPI(320 pixel per inch)
- XXHDPI(640 pixel per inch)
- XXXHDPI(1280 pixel per inch and above)